# Getting Undefined symbol: static error while using local swift package

Tags: ios, swift

I'am trying to use a local swift package that I made for myself. (It is an extension of NSLayoutConstraint that contains static methods that I've added for personal use)

Below is the example of the package code that is causing the error.

```swift
public extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    static func activateTwoWayContraints(subView: UIView, containerView: UIView, top: CGFloat, centerX: CGFloat) {
        
        if subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints {
            subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: top),
            subView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor, constant: centerX)
        ])
    }
```

I had to set the extension as `public` to use it in the project file, else it would cause an error saying that the above function is declared as `internal`.

The package itself builds without any problem but when I build my project that includes this code,

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateTwoWayContraints(subView: label, containerView: view, top: 50, centerX: 0)
```

It causes a weird linker error that says it can't find static symbol.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "static (extension in MisoSwiftTools):__C.NSLayoutConstraint.activateTwoWayContraints(subView: __C.UIView, containerView: __C.UIView, widthMultiply: CoreGraphics.CGFloat, heightMultiply: CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> ()", referenced from:
      UIkitFundamentals.ViewController.setLayout() -> () in ViewController.o
  "static (extension in MisoSwiftTools):__C.NSLayoutConstraint.activateOneWayContraint(targetView: __C.UIView, basisView: __C.UIView, way: MisoSwiftTools.Way, constant: CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> ()", referenced from:
      UIkitFundamentals.ViewController.setLayout() -> () in ViewController.o
  "static (extension in MisoSwiftTools):__C.NSLayoutConstraint.activateTwoWayContraints(subView: __C.UIView, containerView: __C.UIView, top: CoreGraphics.CGFloat, centerX: CoreGraphics.CGFloat) -> ()", referenced from:
      UIkitFundamentals.ViewController.setLayout() -> () in ViewController.o
  "static (extension in MisoSwiftTools):__C.UIView.changeViewBackgroundColor(view: __C.UIView, color: __C.UIColor) -> ()", referenced from:
      UIkitFundamentals.ViewController.setLayout() -> () in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know how compiler, assembler and linker works. And I don't get how the swift compiler is comprehending `static` keyword as a symbol, instead as a keyword for setting the `activateTwoWayContraints` symbol to a local static symbol.

---

The `Package.swift` file of the local swift package:

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MisoSwiftTools",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MisoSwiftTools",
            targets: ["MisoSwiftTools"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MisoSwiftTools",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "Sources"
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MisoSwiftToolsTests",
            dependencies: ["MisoSwiftTools"]),
    ]
)
```

And there is no Package.swift file for the project that is using the local swift file. I suppose the Package.swift file is only used for the swift packages and not all projects?

The local swift package file.

```swift
import Foundation

#if canImport(UIKit)
import UIKit

public enum Way {
    case top
    case bottom
    case leading
    case trailing
}


public enum CustomConstraintsError: Error {
    case vagueAxisError
    
    func getMessage() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .vagueAxisError:
            return "axis should be one of .horizontal or .vertical"
        }
    }
}

public extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    
    /**
     Align top, bottom, leading, trailing constraint to the container view
     - Parameter subView: The target subview.
     - Parameter containerView: The containter view of the target
     
     - Returns: None (Void)
     */
    static func activateFourWayConstraints(subView: UIView, containerView: UIView) {
        
        if subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints {
            subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            subView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            subView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            subView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    static func activateTwoWayContraints(subView: UIView, containerView: UIView, top: CGFloat, centerX: CGFloat) {
        
        if subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints {
            subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: top),
            subView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor, constant: centerX)
        ])
    }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation

#if canImport(UIKit)
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    public static func changeViewBackgroundColor(view: UIView, color: UIColor) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: Having `static` in the symbol name isn't really a problem. That's just how the Swift compiler has been designed/implemented to emit symbols. Can you show what your Package.swift file looks like, for both your local Swift package, and the project that uses the Swift package?

Comment: What _is_ interesting about the symbol name, however, is that the module name for `NSLayoutConstraint` is somehow `__C`, not `UIKit` as one would expect.

Comment: I agree, I though that has something to do with objc, so I've tried marking the extension, static function and enums to @objc but still emits the same error.